# In pt_regs why the value of bp and sp differ so greatly and why bp is smaller than sp

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

When watching the creation of process when tapping ‘ls‘ in terminal, set breakpoint at copy_thread of arch/x86/kernel/process.c with gdb, then print values of pt_regs.

```
{bx = 0x1200011, cx = 0x0, dx = 0x0, si = 0x0, di = 0xa0f38e8, bp = 0x8266000,
  ax = 0xffffffda, ds = 0x7b, __dsh = 0x0, es = 0x7b, __esh = 0x0, fs = 0x0, __fsh = 0x0,
  gs = 0x33, __gsh = 0x0, orig_ax = 0x78, ip = 0xb7f29549, cs = 0x73, __csh = 0x0, flags = 0x206,
  sp = 0xbfab35f0, ss = 0x7b, __ssh = 0x0}
```

the bp of pt_regs is 0x8266000, sp of pt_regs is 0xbfab35f0.
I have find the place where they are assiged.
the sp of pt_regs is assigned in do_SYSENTER_32 of arch/x86/entry/common.c

```
__visible noinstr long do_SYSENTER_32(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    /* SYSENTER loses RSP, but the vDSO saved it in RBP. */
    regs->sp = regs->bp;

    /* SYSENTER clobbers EFLAGS.IF.  Assume it was set in usermode. */
    regs->flags |= X86_EFLAGS_IF;

    return do_fast_syscall_32(regs);
}
```

the bp of pt_regs is assigned in __do_fast_syscall_32 by get_user. It seems from userspace value.

```
static noinstr bool __do_fast_syscall_32(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    // do other stuff...

    /* Fetch EBP from where the vDSO stashed it. */
    if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_X86_64)) {
        /*
         * Micro-optimization: the pointer we're following is
         * explicitly 32 bits, so it can't be out of range.
         */
        res = __get_user(*(u32 *)&regs->bp,
             (u32 __user __force *)(unsigned long)(u32)regs->sp);
    } else {
        res = get_user(*(u32 *)&regs->bp,
               (u32 __user __force *)(unsigned long)(u32)regs->sp);
    }

    // do other stuff...
    return true;
}
```

and the stack shows the order of functions.

```
#0  copy_thread (clone_flags=clone_flags@entry=18874368, sp=0, arg=0, p=0xc31c0a00, tls=0)
    at arch/x86/kernel/process.c:133
#1  0xc1058722 in copy_process (pid=pid@entry=0x0, trace=trace@entry=0, node=node@entry=-1, 
    args=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2122
#2  0xc10593cc in kernel_clone (args=args@entry=0xc68e9f38) at kernel/fork.c:2500
#3  0xc1059807 in __do_sys_clone (child_tidptr=0xa0f38e8, tls=0, parent_tidptr=0x0, newsp=0, 
    clone_flags=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2617
#4  __se_sys_clone (child_tidptr=168769768, tls=0, parent_tidptr=0, newsp=0, 
    clone_flags=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2585
#5  __ia32_sys_clone (regs=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2585
#6  0xc1b04b85 in do_syscall_32_irqs_on (nr=<optimized out>, regs=0xc68e9fb4)
    at arch/x86/entry/common.c:77
#7  __do_fast_syscall_32 (regs=regs@entry=0xc68e9fb4) at arch/x86/entry/common.c:140
#8  0xc1b04c29 in do_fast_syscall_32 (regs=0xc68e9fb4) at arch/x86/entry/common.c:165
#9  0xc1b04c75 in do_SYSENTER_32 (regs=<optimized out>) at arch/x86/entry/common.c:208
#10 0xc1b0e32f in entry_SYSENTER_32 () at arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S:952
#11 0x01200011 in ?? ()
#12 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

I have doubt below:

- Why do the ebp and esp stored in pt_regs differ so greatly?
- Why is the value of ebp stored in pt_regs smaller than the value of
  esp stored in pt_regs, since the stack grows downward?

I used the debuggable linux-5.12.10,and the command 'ls' is compiled from busybox.

Comment: Do you have add_random_kstack_offset enabled?

Comment: @stark no, there is no  'add_random_kstack_offset' in common.c from linux-5.12.10

Comment: `regs->sp` points to the current position on the user stack. After the `get_user()` macro call in `__do_fast_syscall_32()`, `regs->bp` will contain the *arg6* value that was passed on the user stack for the fast system call. Most system calls do not use *arg6* so it can be considered to be a junk value for those system calls. For example, the `clone` system call on IA32 is not defined to use *arg6*.

Comment: For comparison, the legacy INT $0x80 system call mechanism passes the *arg6* value in the EBP register directly (not on the user stack), but it still ends up in `regs->bp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the difference in register and stack usage for the legacy INT $0x80 system call mechanism and the modern fast system call mechanism for IA32:

| Register / stack | Legacy system call | Fast system call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| eax | system call number | system call number |
| ebx | arg1 | arg1 |
| ecx | arg2 | arg2 |
| edx | arg3 | arg3 |
| esi | arg4 | arg4 |
| edi | arg5 | arg5 |
| ebp | arg6 | user stack pointer |
| arg on user stack |  | arg6 |

For the fast system call mechanism, when `entry_SYSENTER_32` constructs the `struct pt_regs` entry on the kernel stack, the `sp` member will point to the kernel stack and the `bp` member will point to the user stack. Therefore, the fast system call mechanism fixes up the `sp` and `bp` members for compatibility with the legacy system call mechanism. The `sp` member value is corrected in `do_SYSENTER_32()`:

```c
    /* SYSENTER loses RSP, but the vDSO saved it in RBP. */
    regs->sp = regs->bp;
```

The `bp` member value is corrected in `__do_fast_syscall_32()`, setting it to the *arg6* value from the user stack:

```c
    /* Fetch EBP from where the vDSO stashed it. */
    if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_X86_64)) {
        /*
         * Micro-optimization: the pointer we're following is
         * explicitly 32 bits, so it can't be out of range.
         */
        res = __get_user(*(u32 *)&regs->bp,
             (u32 __user __force *)(unsigned long)(u32)regs->sp);
    } else {
        res = get_user(*(u32 *)&regs->bp,
               (u32 __user __force *)(unsigned long)(u32)regs->sp);
    }
```

When `do_syscall_32_irqs_on()` is called from `do_int80_syscall_32()` (for the legacy system call mechanism) or from `__do_fast_syscall_32()` (for the fast system call mechanism), the `regs->bp` and `regs->sp` values will be as expected no matter which of the system call mechanisms was used.

---

Another fix-up for fast system calls occurs for `regs->ip`. The original value of the EIP register is lost by the `sysenter` instruction, which is normally executed from the `__kernel_vsyscall()` function in the vDSO.  `regs->ip` is corrected in `do_fast_syscall_32()`:

```c
    /*
     * Called using the internal vDSO SYSENTER/SYSCALL32 calling
     * convention.  Adjust regs so it looks like we entered using int80.
     */
    unsigned long landing_pad = (unsigned long)current->mm->context.vdso +
                    vdso_image_32.sym_int80_landing_pad;

    /*
     * SYSENTER loses EIP, and even SYSCALL32 needs us to skip forward
     * so that 'regs->ip -= 2' lands back on an int $0x80 instruction.
     * Fix it up.
     */
    regs->ip = landing_pad;
```

The vDSO contains an `int $0x80` instruction immediately after the `sysenter` instruction. The `landing_pad` value is the address just after that `int $0x80` instruction, so that instruction will not be reached when returning from the fast system call.

The reason for the `int $0x80` instruction in the vDSO is to support older CPUs that lack the `sysenter` and `sysexit` instructions. In that case, the `mov %esp, %ebp; sysenter` instruction sequence in `__kernel_vsyscall()` in the vDSO will be replaced with `nop` instructions and the CPU will reach the `int $0x80` instruction that immediately follows that instruction sequence, effectively changing the fast system call into a legacy system call for older CPUs. That legacy system call will return to the point just after the `int $0x80` instruction just like the fast system call.

Answer (score 0):

Eighteen days later, I did the experiment again and noticed a strange phenomenon.
I use 32-bit ubuntu system to compile a program, the simplified program is

```
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

Place the compiled a.out into my rootfs.img.gz and start qemu

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 256m -kernel ./bzImage -initrd ./rootfs.img.gz -append "root=/dev/ram init=/linuxrc nokaslr" -serial file:output.txt -s -S
```

Then use gdb, set `break copy_thread`

I enter the command ./a.out in shell of linux in qemu.

Because there is a code `*childregs = *current_pt_regs()` in copy_thread function, I can watch the user stack info by print childregs

When shell create process of a.out, the linux kernel stopped at copy_thread. At the time I enter `p/x *childregs`

```
(gdb) p/x *childregs
$10 = {bx = 0x1200011, cx = 0x0, dx = 0x0, si = 0x0, di = 0x9acb3e8, 
  bp = 0x8289000, ax = 0xffffffda, ds = 0x7b, __dsh = 0x0, es = 0x7b, 
  __esh = 0x0, fs = 0x0, __fsh = 0x0, gs = 0x33, __gsh = 0x0, orig_ax = 0x78, 
  ip = 0xb7f93549, cs = 0x73, __csh = 0x0, flags = 0x216, sp = 0xbfe797ec, 
  ss = 0x7b, __ssh = 0x0}
```

The shell's stack info is `bp = 0x8289000,sp = 0xbfe797ec`.  bp's value is very strange.

When a.out run fork(), the linux kernel stopped at copy_thread again. At the time I enter `p/x *childregs`.

```
(gdb) p/x *childregs
$11 = {bx = 0x1200011, cx = 0x0, dx = 0x0, si = 0x0, di = 0xb7eeb128, 
  bp = 0xbfa23818, ax = 0xffffffda, ds = 0x7b, __dsh = 0x0, es = 0x7b, 
  __esh = 0x0, fs = 0x0, __fsh = 0x0, gs = 0x33, __gsh = 0x0, orig_ax = 0x78, 
  ip = 0xb7ef0549, cs = 0x73, __csh = 0x0, flags = 0x246, sp = 0xbfa237d0, 
  ss = 0x7b, __ssh = 0x0}
```

The a.out stack info is `bp = 0xbfa23818，sp = 0xbfa237d0`. bp's value is larger than sp's value, and the differ between the values is not so much greatly. This is what I expected

But when shell create a.out process, the bp is 0x8289000, I don't know what exactly happened at that time.

Comment: the program should be compiled in 32 bit ubuntu. the ld-linux.so.2 and libc.so.6 should also be from 32 bit ubuntu.